# How do I use syslog4j with logback

Tags: logback

I am using logback for my logging. I wanted to use syslog4j to natively log to syslog.(as I do not want to open up the udp port for logging into syslog)
Can I use syslog4j as an appender to logback? If not, is there any other way of using logback to log into syslog without opening up the udp port i.e. using native unix sockets!

Thanks
Sumanth

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for [SyslogAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender)

configuration example here [logback-syslog.xml](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters/appenders/conf/logback-syslog.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the SyslogAppender in Logback doesn't support anything other than UDP syslog protocol.

I haven't tried but it might be trivial to write a Syslog4jAppender for Logback (I'm surprised no-one else has already)

It hasn't been answered yet but the question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905480/using-syslog4j-as-an-appender-to-logback" would cover what you want.